# Why my Google Now on my Motorola Razr D3 will not reply with voice?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, voice-command, google-now

I just saw [this vídeo](http://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=kDsOtdRtG0Q&desktop_uri=/watch?v=kDsOtdRtG0Q) about Google Now, but I don't have the same behavior on my Motorola Razr D3, with Android 4.1.2. I got the search results, but with no voice reply.

Is it the voice reply exclusive for Samsung phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voice reply isn't exclusive for Samsung phones: I get it with the same "what's the weather" query on a [nexus-7](/questions/tagged/nexus-7). But it's controlled by a setting in Google Now. From the main window, go to the menu and choose **Settings**. From the settings page, you want **Voice**, then **Speech output**. Set it how you like.

But take note that you only get a voice reply for the special queries that Google Now is programmed for, not for web searches. To get a list of these special queries, press the microphone icon and ask, "Help."

Comment: I already did that, but it didn't work. But I just realized that if I set all my phone (not only the Google Now) to English it will work fine. Also, I realized that the Pico TTS don't have my language, so this may be an issue.

Comment: Actually, installing a TTS language for Portuguese (in my case) is not working. Everything must be in English, the google now, and the phone itself.